# Firebase Firestore Keeping the users after i delete them

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have created an quiz app with android studio and you can create an account and Log In. For the testing i have created multiple accounts and now i deleted them from the firestore. I can still Log In and perform actions with the old users that i have deleted from firestore. Why is this happening?

Comment: Firestore doesn't have user accounts, but Firebase Authentication does. Is that where you deleted the users? And do you mean that they still have access to Firestore data after deleting them? If so, did you **just** delete them? If so, this may be expected behavior: auth tokens are valid for an hour, and deleting a user does not revoke their existing token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean that Firebase users can still access data in Firestore after you deleted their account, that may be working as expected if you're trying it right after the account has been deleted.

Firebase auth ID tokens are valid for an hour, and deleting a user does not revoke their existing ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation for a longer explanation, and ways to deal with it. The latter typically involves flagging the deleted user account in the database, and then also checking against that record in your security rules.

A final note: consider disabling the account instead of deleting it. This prevents the user from creating a new account with the same credentials.

Comment: thank you yes I was passing into the firestore the users and deleted them from there but in authenticator they were still there.